# How should I configure MoinMoin page text searches to ignore its own help files?

Tags: moinmoin

My software team uses a MoinMoin wiki to record our coding guidelines and other best practices. Like most wikis, each page includes a basic search box, and MoinMoin offers both "Titles" and "Text" command buttons. (The former matches page names only and the latter does a full-text search.)

By default, each MoinMoin page's search box returns too much information, because it matches both wiki content and the application's own (voluminous) help pages. Its advanced search page--also called **FindPage**--can omit help searches via the **Exclude underlay** checkbox, but we'd like to make that its *default* behavior. Unfortunately, the engineer who set up our wiki doesn't know how to make that change. How can we limit basic text searches to group content only?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there was an advanced search page, where you could find *"Don't search help pages"* checkbox. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks--that helps, though we'd prefer to search only team-generated pages by default. Deleting the help directory might do the job, but we hope it doesn't come to that. :-)

Comment: Edited my question to mention the advanced search specifically, which avoids help file matches using the (oddly named) "Exclude underlay" check box.